# Python package installation issue when docker build based on r-base docker image

Tags: python, r, docker

I want to install python in a r-base docker image. When I try this:

```
FROM r-base:3.4.1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3
```

I get error:

```
Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

When I try this:

```
FROM r-base:3.5.1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3
```

I get error:

```
The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian testing Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I can use both R and Python if I start with a jupyter notebook base, but I really want this image to be slim so I want to start with r-base instead. Note that USER root did not solve these issues either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really strange as see this [link](http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/)

> The server deb.debian.org does not have packages itself, but the name has SRV records in DNS that let apt in stretch and later find places.

Maybe your local network is something special, something like:

> If you hit the server behind deb.debian.org directly, either because you use an older apt or because you use a HTTP proxy that does not support SRV records, your requests will get HTTP redirected to one of the CDN instances. If you want to avoid the redirects, you can pick one instance directly.

So, suggest add a direct source of apt in your `Dockerfile`, something like follows:

```
FROM r-base:3.5.1

RUN echo "deb http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  echo "deb http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  rm -fr /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/default && \
  apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3
```

If you have proxy, please also add something like `ENV http_proxy "http://your_proxy"` to `Dockerfile`, hope it helpful.

Comment: yeah, seems to be due to my work network. thanks for your help.